# SCILAB-How to implement post or pre increment in the code

Tags: scilab

How do I perform increment function on scilab?

I tried to run the following code on scilab but unsuccessful.

```
a=0;
even=0;
odd=0;

for x=1:10
a=a+1
if modulo(a,2)==0
disp("Even");
even++;
else
disp("Odd");
odd++;
end
disp(even);
disp(odd);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Scilab does not support C-style incrementing syntax (i.e. `even++`, `odd++`).  You need to explicitly do an assignment and add 1 to the variable.  Therefore:

```
a=0;
even=0;
odd=0;

for x=1:10
    a=a+1;
    if modulo(a,2)==0
        disp("Even");
        even = even + 1; %// Change
    else
        disp("Odd");
        odd = odd + 1; %// Change
    end
    disp(even);
    disp(odd);
end
```

However, having a variable `a` with a loop counter `x` that increments in the same method as `a` is rather superfluous.  Consider replacing the loop counter with `a` and starting your loop from 0 and ending at 9:

```
even=0;
odd=0;

for a=0:9 %// Change
    if modulo(a,2)==0
        disp("Even");
        even = even + 1; %// Change
    else
        disp("Odd");
        odd = odd + 1; %// Change
    end
    disp(even);
    disp(odd);
end
```

---

A more efficient vectorized approach would be to use `sum` instead of doing a loop.  You can easily do what you want by:

```
a=0:9;
even = sum(modulo(a,2) == 0);
odd = sum(modulo(a,2) == 1);
disp(even);
disp(odd);
```